# How to connect my phone to Visual Studio 2013 with Xamarin?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin-studio

I have Visual Studio 2013 with Xamarin Android and iOS. Then I have some emulators there, but I don't like them. How do I connect my phone, so that Visual Studio or Xamarin anyway detects my phone and try my application in my phone. My phone is a Sony.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with physical android device you have to install drivers for that device.

Use [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to test if you installed drivers correctly via "adb devices" command. Once adb detects your device VisualStudio and XamarinStudio will also see your device and you will be able to debug on device.